# Need guidance with Hashmap and resultset

Tags: java, hashmap, resultset

The resultset will return different set of data eg:

```
> Winter    1001    112 
> Summer    1001    112 
> Autumn    1001    110 
> Spring    1001    111
> Winter    1002    112 
> Summer    1002    116 
> Autumn    1002    110 
> Spring    1002    115
> Winter    1003    112 
> Autumn    1003    111 
> Spring    1003    115 
> Summer    1003    112
```

and the data i need to display is in this format:

> I got data [winter,summer,Autumn,Spring] [data1] [112,112,110,111]
>   [data2] [112,116,110,115] [data3][112,111,115,112]

I was writing the code and this is something what i have got

```
if (connection != null) {
                System.out.println("Got DB Connection!");
                String selectTableSQL = sql;
                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectTableSQL);
                while (rs.next()) {
                    caltList.add("\""+rs.getString(1)+"\"");
                    dataList.add(rs.getString(3));
                }

                }

String result = "";
String gotData = "I got data "
result = String.format(res,gotData,caltList,dataList);
```

Can somebody guide with the Hashmap or some approach .. am new to java... and unable to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

I think I would fill a `LinkedHashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Integer>` with the data from the `ResultSet` in this way:

```
LinkedHashMap [
  => 1001
       => "Winter" => 112
       => "Summer" => 112
       => "Autumn" => 110
       => "Spring" => 111

  => 1002
       => "Winter" => 112
       => "Summer" => 116
       => "Autumn" => 110
       => "Spring" => 115
  => ...
]
```

Then in a second loop I would create the output which you expect from it.
(`[winter,summer,Autumn,Spring] [data1] [112,112,110,111] [data2] [112,116,110,115] ...]`).

That's why I chose a `LinkedHashMap` because it keeps the order in which you add it's entries. So it is assured that `data1` is the first entry in the Map and so on.

Comment: I know its too much to ask but can you please help with the code?

Comment: @user2572739 If you have a question you can ask. But I won't write your code.

Comment: ... if this is a homework question, my answer is too generic I think.

Comment: Actually am new to java.. and im put up in java team to complete a part of project.. as its in RED status.. I had guessed that i sud be using hashmap or something but not able to proceed as how to iterate and add data in resultset..

Comment: This is wher am stuck at LinkedHashMap<String,HashMap<Integer,String>> linkedHashm = new LinkedHashMap<String, HashMap<Integer,String>>();
    while (rs.next()) {
     linkedHashm.add(rs.getString(1),);